# PHP Library for JSX Compilation

Tags: php, reactjs

I have used the following code for importing React JavaScript library and JSX compiler:

```
<script src="build/react.js"></script>
<script src="build/react-dom.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/babel-core/5.8.23/browser.min.js">
</script>
```

I want to compile JSX using a server-side library, instead of using

```
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/babel-core/5.8.23/browser.min.js">
</script>
```

Which is around 1MB. So, is there any PHP Library available for JSX Compilation?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You really shouldn't be using Babel in the browser. Take the time to learn how to set up a build environment that uses Babel to precompile your JavaScript. The typical workflow uses Babel in conjunction with either Webpack or Browserify to bundle your modules.

Official documentation:

- https://babeljs.io/
- https://webpack.github.io/ or http://browserify.org/ (pick one)

If you need React server side rendering within a PHP backend, you might like to check out https://github.com/reactjs/react-php-v8js. It doesn't do JSX compilation, just server side rendering. So you still need to precompile your JavaScript.

Comment: The OP is clearly seeking an alternative to client side transcoding.

Answer (score 1):

If you want to use **React** **server-side rendering** from **PHP**, check this **library**:

https://github.com/Limenius/ReactRenderer